# when opeing spyder getting No module named 'PyQt4'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

When i am opening spyder on ubuntu 16.04 os i am getting following error

```
NOTE: The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/kernel.py", line 471, in _set_mpl_backend
    get_ipython().run_line_magic(magic, backend)
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2131, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-107>", line 2, in matplotlib
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
    gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3049, in enable_matplotlib
    pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py", line 310, in activate_matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5agg import (
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py", line 54, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 153, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

I update conda and all other things by `conda update anaconda`. but still getting problem

Comment: You need to install PyQt4, or change the default backend

Comment: can you please guide how to do this

Comment: thnx. problem solved. we have to just do `matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'Qt5Agg'`

Comment: But one thing here is that, when i closed and again open spyder, then same prlb occurs. Is that mean always i have to write and run  `matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'Qt5Agg'` What is permanent solution

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please look for a `matplotlibrc` file in your system. The matplotlib backend is probably set there and that's what's causing this error.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba yup i know this point. `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` i used. but this is very big file. i donot know where to do changes

Comment: Just comment the line that sets the backend, so that Spyder can set by itself.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba there is only one uncommented line matplotlibrc file which is `backend      : qt5agg` i commented this but again i have same problem.

Comment: Weird, I don't know what's happening in your case, sorry.